# Fetch specific tag value from response object

Tags: php, xml

[Can anyone let me know how to fetch the [response] value from the below response object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLdLz.png)

SimpleXMLElement Object
(

```
[MaterialInfo] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        
        [QueryList] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [identity] => EUROHS-0508
                            )

                        [Query] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                    (
                                        [@attributes] => Array
                                            (
                                                [statement] => Product Meets EU RoHS Requirements Without Any Exemptions
                                                [response] => false
                                            )

                                    )
```

Comment: What have you tried, show us your best attempt (code). Where are you stuck? Do you get any error(s)? please read [ask]!

Comment: Have tried below but no luck
echo "\n --->". $querylist_stmnt->MaterialInfo->QueryList[0]->Query[0];
echo $querylist_stmnt['MaterialInfo']['QueryList'][0]['Query'][0]['@attributes']['response'];

Comment: Rahul S, just an idea for some of your questions visitors it might be better to edit the code properly into the question.